# What are the visual differences between Trent 892 and 900 engines?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, multi-engine

Are there any visual differences between a Trent 892 and a Trent 900 engine?
Particularly referring to the ones mounted on the 777-200.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference between the two installed engines would be the fan blades. The 892 uses hollow wide chord Ti blades, like shown below.

[image: Trent 892]

By Cory W. Watts from Madison, Wisconsin, United States of America - Rolls Royce Trent 892 [777-200ER], CC BY-SA 2.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=43524027

The Trent 900, on the other hand, uses a swept design to reduces the effect of shock waves. From [RR site](http://www.rolls-royce.com/products-and-services/civil-aerospace/products/civil-large-engines/trent-900.aspx#technology):

> The engine’s 24 fan blades are to a new swept design that reduces the effect of shock waves, as the tip of the fan rotates supersonically, making it lighter, quieter and more efficient

[image: Trent 900]

Image from [imagesourcemedia.com](http://www.imageresourcemedia.com/broadcast/streaming_site/pages/Trent%20900%20build.jpg); appears to be taken from RR site.

Also, the Trent 900 is exclusively for A380.